# Mongo Update keeps adding to the size of the collection

Tags: mongodb, python

I am running a scraper to check for this one thing to change, so I have no idea why my Mongo database keeps growing when all I do is an update on this single data.

I only have one item in the database, with a post_id : 1. In my code all I am doing is updating it. (Python)

```
client = MongoClient(DB_URL)
db = client.chatScrape

collection = db.posts

#insert scraped data
result = collection.update({'post_id' : 1}, scraped, upsert = True)

client.close()
```

So after the first execution I get:

```
> db.posts.find().count()
> 1
```

But after an hour or so I get:

```
> db.posts.find().count()
> 2
```

After about a week or so, the number grows to 10+, so what is going on here? Shouldn't update only modify one item and not make more?

Comment: Are all of the documents with a `post_id` of 1 still?

Comment: Only one of the document in the collection is post_id of 1.

Comment: is post_id an auto incrementing field?

Comment: Nope. It is static. The other document do no have a post_id. The other are just documents containing data. It looks like it is extending the post_id... Which is strange because the document size is always the same. I am expecting the update to overwrite the original document. But from what I am seeing new data into post_id of 1 and moving the old stuff to another document.

Comment: Can you show us what is in the _scraped_ variable?

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard a guess that your code is running the upsert command fairly quickly. It may depend on your MongoDB version, but on the latest version an update command which does not [specify update modifiers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) will just overwrite the entire document, which involves deleting and re-writing it.

It seems likely that in between another upsert operation, a second upsert is run and when it sees no document it inserts a new one. In this case you might want to look at *not* updating the entire document.

You could also look into using a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) and a little re-try logic which might work for you based on how infrequently this appears to be happening.